# Refactoring node.js database code

Tags: javascript

I have a user model.

It basically forwards get/create/delete requests into my database client.

The problem I have is the error handling, it screams not DRY to me, but I can't find an elegant way to clean it up.

```
var UserModel = pd.make(Model, {
    get: function _get(id, cb) {
        // nano is a database client
        this.nano.get(id, 
            // whitelist runs every error through the white list,
            // if it fails (false) throw it
            // if it succeeds (true) pass it to cb
            // if the return value is undefined it does nothing
            error.whitelist(function _errors(err) {
                // getaddrinfo is a random DNS error I have to swallow
                // no clue where the bug comes from, trying again is the easy fix
                if (err.syscall === 'getaddrinfo') {
                    UserModel.get(id, cb);
                } else if (err.error === "not_found") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, cb)
        );
    },
    insert: function _create(json, cb) {
        this.nano.insert(json, json._id, 
            error.whitelist(function _errors(err) {
                if (err.syscall === 'getaddrinfo') {
                    UserModel.insert(json, cb);
                } else if (err.error === "conflict") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, cb)
        );
    },
    delete: function _delete(name, cb) {
        var that = this;
        this.get(name, function _getRev(err, body) {
            that.nano.destroy(name, body._rev, 
                error.whitelist(function _errors(err) {
                    if (err.syscall === 'getaddrinfo') {
                        UserModel.delete(name, cb);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }, cb)
            );
        });
    }
});
```

[pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd), [error](https://github.com/Raynos/error), [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano)

Answer (score 2):

Based on feedback from [JavaScript chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1900602#1900602). Credit to @Zirak and @Chris

You want a hash of white listed error messages for each method

```
var whitelistMap = {
    "get": ["not_found"],
    "insert": ["conflict"],
    "delete": []
}
```

You want a whitelist error handler factory. This will include the "getaddrinfo" code for every method which is basically a try again short cutting.

It will check whether the error message is in the whitelistMap for that method and if so will let that error through.

otherwise it simply throws

```
function makeWhitelistCallback(method, thing, cb) {
    return error.whitelist(function _errors(err) {
        if (err.syscall === "getaddrinfo") {
            UserModel[method](thing, cb);
        } else if (whitelistMap[method].indexOf(err.error) !== -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, cb);
}
```

And the rest of the code simply calls the whitelist callback factory

```
var UserModel = pd.make(Model,{
    get: function _get(id, cb) {
        this.nano.get(id, 
            makeWhitelistCallback("get", id, cb)
        );
    },
    insert: function _create(json, cb) {
        this.nano.insert(json, json._id, 
            makeWhitelistCallback("insert", json, cb)
        );
    },
    delete: function _delete(name, cb) {
        var that = this;
        this.get(name, function _getRev(err, body) {
            that.nano.destroy(name, body._rev, 
                makeWhitelistCallback("delete", name, cb)
            );
        });
    }
});
```